# Hilight/select a file with a batch script

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch-file, cmd.exe

I would like to make a batch file that first opens the location of a specific file then selects, but doesn't open said file. Is there a way to do this? Currently I have this in my script:

```
if not exist "%TARGETPATH%" mkdir "%TARGETPATH%"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%TARGETFILEPATH%"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way works for me:

```
set targetfilepath=c:\temp\test.txt    
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETFILEPATH%"
```

Edit: this way the file will be **selected and not opened**, that's **exactly** what was asked.
Maybe the downvoter did not carefully read the question or did not try my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, and your method worked flawlessly. Sorry someone down voted your answer.