# Can I use a batch file to hilight a specific file format?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I've been experimenting with batch files lately, and recently I found an answer to an old question: [Hilight/select a file with a batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/1193480/hilight-select-a-file-with-a-batch-script). Now that I have accomplished that, I would like to know if the same method can be used with a format variable (i.e. *.txt). More specifically, I would like to create a script to do the same for image files like .jpg, and .png that searches for *all* specified formats in a given disk, or path. This is the template I used:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGET%"
```

I have already tried simply placing the variables *.jpg and *.png in the place of %TARGET% both with, and without quotation marks.  I am also *well* aware that this could take a tremendous amount of time given the ammount of images, computer performance, ect... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have insufficient experience with this, but I would assume you would first need to enumerate a list of files, and then parse that as target.

Comment: Why? All I needed to do was use the same line of code in my previous script, and create a new line for each target. When executed, each target would be presented and hilighted simultaneously. I would imagine that using only a format or other common variable would cause the script to do the same starting from the root path of the script on. But I also am still fairly new to batch programming.

Comment: Its just that I think that explorer doesn't support *.??? as parameter

Comment: I am unsure of that, as I do know how to make a script that can _delete_ a specified format/extension. That's why I believe this is possible. Also: I am making this as a tool to find images the user cannot find (for whatever reason), so using a pre-defined list is out of the question. Perhaps I could use a list of pre-defined paths, as I have a general idea of where the images may be... I appreciate your input though.

Comment: commandline tools can use wildcards. So yes, you can del *.jpg. But passing that to explorer, not sure if explorer knows what to do with it. So I think you would need to go into the direction of first generating a list. For example `forfiles *.jpg ....`

Comment: According to this, it cannot be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programmatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer

Comment: I suggest you use FreeCommander/TotalCommander/FarManager they all can select/highlight with the [plus] key and a wildcard.

Comment: Mr. Mendelli - I know I'm late to the game but thought I'd add this answer since I ran across this post and had something already that needed tweaked just a bit to work as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Can I use a batch file to highlight a specific file format?**

You most certainly can use a batch script to select all (or highlight all) files with a specific file extension that are all in the same one folder using [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) and [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) as the below example.

### Batch Script Example

*Be sure to change the value of the `SET Extension=` and the `SET Folder=` variables to be what you need those to be to suffice for the need.*

*Please note that if you want to search for multiple file extensions with this method, then the variable value of the `SET Extension=` variable should have each extension separated by `OR` for example if you want to see TXT, PDF, and BMP files, you'd use `SET Extension=*.txt OR *.pdf OR *.bmp`.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET Folder=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
SET Extension=*.txt
:::SET Extension=*.txt OR *.pdf OR *.bmp
EXPLORER "%Folder%"

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{F3}"                             >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%Extension%"                      >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^a"                               >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

EXIT
```

> **Note:** *The above script was tested with **Windows 10**. If you are using **Windows 7**, you need to be sure to use `"{TAB 3}"` rather
>   than `"{TAB 2}"` so it presses the tab key three times.*

---

### Further Resources

- [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I thought this would end up being unsolvable with batch scripting. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: All I need to do now is program the script to search multiple extensions at once.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli This is possible here just use `SET Extension=*.txt OR *.pdf OR *.bmp` like that in place of the `SET Extension=*.txt`. Let me know if that helps or you still have trouble.

Comment: I thought I should point out that using `{TAB 2}` on Windows 7 seemed to have no effect, and that the script worked anyways...

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli I had to make it `{TAB 3}` on the Windows 7 machine I tested it with. Are you saying it worked on your Windows 7 system as-is in the script example I provided?

Comment: Yes, there didn't seem to be *any* differences in the performance using `{TAB 2}` or `{TAB 3}`.